# How to fix the compile error in this Kotlin StateFlow code with Kotlin 1.9.10?

Tags: android, kotlin

The code:

```
/**
 * Like [Flow.map], but returns a [StateFlow] rather than a [Flow]. As a consequence, [transform]
 * cannot be a suspend function.
 */
fun <T, R> StateFlow<T>.mapStateFlow(transform: (T) -> R): StateFlow<R> = MapStateFlow(this, transform, this.map { transform(it) })

private class MapStateFlow<T, R>(private val inStateFlow: StateFlow<T>, private val transform: (T) -> R, private val outFlow: Flow<R>) : Flow<R> by outFlow, StateFlow<R> {
    override val value: R
        get() = transform(inStateFlow.value)
    override val replayCache: List<R>
        get() = listOf(value)
}
```

The error:

> Type of 'public open suspend fun collect(collector: FlowCollector):
> Unit defined in com.organum.playscore.utils.extensions.MapStateFlow'
> is not a subtype of overridden by delegation 'public abstract suspend
> fun collect(collector: FlowCollector): Nothing defined in
> kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow'

I understand that collect() defined in Flow has no return type, while collect() defined in StateFlow returns Nothing (which is a special class).
I don't know what has changed so that this code no longer compiles. This was written by a developer who is no longer with us and I have no idea what this is trying to achieve beyond what it says in the comment.

Comment: This looks like a hack by someone that doesn't understand flows. They tried to decorate a stateflow with blocking transform so you can read .value and have it transformed in-line whenever getter is called. Honestly I recommend replacing it with `.map{}.stateIn()` that will do transformations eagerly.

Comment: Thanks, but I am a poor C++ coder with no understanding of Kotlin! This is called from: 
'val featuresOrNull: StateFlow<Set<FeatureModel>?> = currentSubscriptionOrNull
        .mapStateFlow {
            if (it == null) {...'
What do I substitute for mapStateFlow, or does everything have to completely change? Thanks in advance.